# AWS Api Gateway Invalid request body when value is null

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I use Spring boot, swagger (contract first) and React as client.

I have Api Gateway based on same swagger file.

When client send POST request with body containts null values (not empty), API Gateway (based on swagger file) refuses the request.

On local (not use swagger), the properties from Spring (default-property-inclusion: non_empty) let accept null value.

But on AWS, API Gateway return (Invalid request body).

For exemple, for body :

- **{"var1": "val1"}  -> OK**
- **{"var1": "val1", "var2": null}  -> KO**

How to avoid this problem on AWS API Gateway ?

Is there a property equivalent to default-property-inclusion ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the schema for POST request body? Note that AWS API Gateway [requries that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis) the schemas be defined using JSON Schema draft 4 rather than OpenAPI schema syntax. This probably means AWS wants nullable fields to be defined as `type: [string, "null"]` (even though this is not valid in OpenAPI 2.0/3.0). There are [tools](https://github.com/openapi-contrib/openapi-schema-to-json-schema) that can convert OpenAPI schemas to JSON Schema.

Comment: Thank you @Helen for your response.
The file contains a lot of object, it is tedious to modify it.
I will investigate if there is another solution otherwise I will use your solution.

Comment: @A.Hafid I tried the solution proposed by Helen I then checked the Model int he API Gateway console and noted that API Gateway stripped out the type information completely but I could indeed submit the payload where the field held the value null or a string value.